# Creating graphs with google apps script Charts Service produces low quality images

Tags: google-apps-script

When I create a chart programatically, transform into an image and append to a document, the quality of the image is inferior to than one created directly on the document (manually).

Any ideas if this can be fixed?

This is how I am creating it

```
var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable()
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'Área')
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, '# sessões')

  var i = 1;
  var extra = 0;
  var data = []
  for(var r in users_sessions_area) {
    var current = users_sessions_area[r] 
    if(i <= 5 && current.area && current.area != '') {
      dataTable.addRow([current.area, Number(current.sessions)]);
      data.push([current.area, Number(current.sessions)]);
    } else {
      extra += Number(current.sessions);
    }
    i++;
  }

  if(extra > 0) {
    dataTable.addRow(["Outras", extra]);
    data.push(["Outras", extra]);
  }

  sheet.getRange("A2:B" + (data.length + 1)).setValues(data);

  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];

  var graphData = Charts.newPieChart().setDataTable(dataTable);
  graphData.setTitle("% sobre o total de sessões");
  graphData.setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.BOTTOM);

  var chart = graphData.build();
  return chart.getAs('image/png');
```

And then adding it to the doc

```
  body.findText("%%SESSION_AREAS_CHART%%").getElement().getParent().asParagraph().appendInlineImage(createSessionsPerAreaChart(variables));
```

Comment: Thanks for the question.  I had a similar experience but the client was happy so I moved on.  But looking forward to seeing some answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put the image of chart to Google Document with the high resolution.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, at the default settings, when the chart is retrieved as an image blob, the resolution is low. So in this case, it is required to retrieve the chart as the image blob after it set the chart to the high resolution. By this, the chart can be put to Google Document as the image with the high resolution.

In order to set the high resolution to the chart, in this answer, it uses `setDimensions()`. When `setDimensions()` is used, the chart size can be done large. But the font size is not set automatically large. So it is required to also set the font size.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var chart = graphData.build();
```

#### To:

```
var chart = graphData.setDimensions(1000, 1000).setOption("fontSize", 40).build();
```

and

#### From:

```
body.findText("%%SESSION_AREAS_CHART%%").getElement().getParent().asParagraph().appendInlineImage(createSessionsPerAreaChart(variables));
```

#### To:

```
var image = body.findText("%%SESSION_AREAS_CHART%%").getElement().getParent().asParagraph().appendInlineImage(createSessionsPerAreaChart(variables));
image.setWidth(500).setHeight(500);
```

### Note:

- At above modified script, as the test case, the base resolution is set to 1000 x 1000 pixels. And the font size is 40. And the retrieved image is put to Google Document by setting to 500 x 500 pixels.

  - About this, please modify them for your actual situation.
- If you want to independently change the font size of title and legend in the chart, you can also use [`setTitleTextStyle()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/area-chart-builder.html#setTitleTextStyle(TextStyle)) and [`setLegendTextStyle()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/area-chart-builder.html#setLegendTextStyle(TextStyle)).
- If you want to reflect above to other chart, it might be required to modify other parameters. So please be careful this.

### References:

- [Visualization: Pie Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)
- [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts)
- [Class TextStyleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/text-style-builder.html#setFontSize(Number))
- [Class InlineImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image.html)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Ramon Canales Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: @Ramon Canales Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: really sorry the delay getting back to you... It worked perfectly, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Ramon Canales Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.